# ¿Porqué no se cambia el valor de esta matriz?

Tags: c#, matrices, bucle-for, condiciones

Ejercicio: Construya un programa que le permita generar una matriz de tres filas y cinco columnas como la mostrada en la figura de abajo.  Luego permita ingresar valores hasta llenar toda la matriz, a continuación, genere un mecanismo para determinar si el valor del centro es cero, y si es así, automáticamente rellene con uno el valor el primer y último valor ingresado.  En pantalla debe mostrarse la matriz ingresada al inicio y luego la matriz transformada según lo anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Parcial_3___Ejercicio_1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] Matriz = new int[3, 5];
        int[,] Matriz2 = new int[3, 5];
        int contador = 1, contador2 = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(int a = 0; a<3; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor " + contador + "x" + contador2 + " :");
                Matriz[a, i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Matriz2[a, i] = Matriz[a, i];
                contador++;
            }
            contador2++;
            contador = 1;
        }

        if(Matriz[2,3] == 0)
        {
            Matriz[1, 1] = 1;
            Matriz[2, 3] = 1;
            Matriz[3, 5] = 1;
        }
        contador = 1;
        contador2 = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Matriz original: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fila: " + contador + ". Columna: " + contador2 + ". : ");
                Console.WriteLine(Matriz2[a, i]);
            }
            contador2++;
            contador = 1;
        }

        contador = 1;
        contador2 = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Matriz convetida: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fila: " + contador + ". Columna: " + contador2 + ". : ");
                Console.WriteLine(Matriz[a, i]);
            }
            contador2++;
            contador = 1;
        }




        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Problema: No cambia el valor de la posición Matriz[3,5] a 1.
A la hora de imprimir la matriz "convertida" da siempre el valor ingresado y no el asignado después del if. Los demás valores si los cambia.

Comment: Los arreglos deben empezar en 0, además al imprimir no estás incrementando `contador`

Comment: Si declaras una matriz de 5x3 jamas puedes asignar un valor con indices iguales o mayores a los rangos, ya que como bien dice @Ali los indices de cualquier Array uni o bidimensional empiezan en 0, con lo que igual estas buscando es Matriz[2,4]

Comment: @Ali Los contadores solo los estoy usando como muletillas que permiten al usuario saber en qué pocisión de la matriz va. Y no entiendo por qué dicen que deben de empezar en cero, si justamente, en esas posisiciónes los estoy recorriendo para empezar a trabajar. Las variables "a" e "i" dentro de los "for" son los que en realidad indican la pocisión de las matrices. No las varibles "contador".

Comment: El que dice Matriz[1,1] estás evaluando el dato que está en la segunda fila y segunda columna, al decir Matriz[2,3] está evaluando el dato que está en la tercera fila, cuarta columna, por eso te digo que los arreglos empiezan con 0.. y si vi que contador no es la posición, es un utilitario, yo usaría el indice pero si vas a usar contador tienes que incrementarlo si no, siempre imprimirá 1.

Answer (score 1):

Los arrays son base cero. Por lo que tus contadores deberían ser igual a cero, que por otra parte, en realidad sobran, podrías poner algo así directamente(Lo que te solucionaría el problema al imprimir, ya que lo que ocurre es que no aumenta el contador):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Fila " + a + " Columna " + i + " :");
        Matriz[a, i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Matriz2[a, i] = Matriz[a, i];
        //contador++;
      }
        //contador2++;
        //contador = 1;
}
```

Yo tu ejercicio lo resolvería con algo así:

```
 class Program
    {
        static int[,] originalArray;
        static int[,] copyArray;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userInput;

            do
            {
                PrintMenu();
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case "1":
                        CreateArray();
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        AutoFillArray(true);
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        AutoFillArray(false);
                        break;

                    case "4":
                        CheckZero();
                        break;

                    case "5":
                        PrintArrays();
                        break;

                    case "6":
                        PrintMenu();
                        break;

                    case "9":
                        break;

                    default:
                        PrintMenu();
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            } while (userInput != "9");
        }

        private static void CheckZero()
        {
            switch (originalArray[1, 2])
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("The center number is: " + originalArray[1, 2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reordering array");
                    ReorderArray();
                    Console.WriteLine("Original array");
                    PrintArray(originalArray);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reordered array");
                    PrintArray(copyArray);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("The center number is: " + originalArray[1, 2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Is not neccesary reorder the array");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void ReorderArray()
        {
            copyArray = (int[,])originalArray.Clone();
            copyArray[0, 0] = 1;
            copyArray[2, 4] = 1;
        }

        private static void PrintArrays()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Original Array");
            PrintArray(originalArray);
            Console.WriteLine("Copied Array");
            PrintArray(copyArray);
        }

        private static void PrintArray(int[,] arrayToPrint)
        {
            StringBuilder printLine = new StringBuilder();

            if (arrayToPrint != null)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {
                        printLine.Append(arrayToPrint[r, c] + " ");
                        if (c == 4)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(printLine.ToString());
                            printLine = new StringBuilder();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The array is null!!");
            }

        }

        private static void AutoFillArray(bool isZero)
        {
            originalArray = new int[3, 5];
            originalArray[0, 0] = 7;
            originalArray[0, 1] = 4;
            originalArray[0, 2] = 2;
            originalArray[0, 3] = 5;
            originalArray[0, 4] = 7;


            originalArray[1, 0] = 5;
            originalArray[1, 1] = 2;
            if (isZero)
            {
                originalArray[1, 2] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                originalArray[1, 2] = 1;
            }

            originalArray[1, 3] = 2;
            originalArray[1, 4] = 6;

            originalArray[2, 0] = 4;
            originalArray[2, 1] = 5;
            originalArray[2, 2] = 5;
            originalArray[2, 3] = 4;
            originalArray[2, 4] = 4;
        }

        private static void CreateArray()
        {
            originalArray = new int[3, 5];
        }

        private static void PrintMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1) Create arrays 3,5");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Auto fill with zero");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Auto fill without zero");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Check center number and change first and last item");
            Console.WriteLine("5) Print arrays");
            Console.WriteLine("6) Reprint menu");
            Console.WriteLine("9) Exit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1- Los contadores de los ciclos de repetición están declarados de forma interna. Las variables llamadas "contadores" no son para el manejo de los ciclos. Son solo muletillas que ayudan al usuario saber en qué posición del vector va. 2- El ejercicio es en programación secuencial básica, no está permitido el uso de métodos.